# The definition of $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, definition

Let $\{ a_n \}_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ be a sequence whose domain is $\mathbb Z$ (not $\mathbb N$).

I'm confused with the definition of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n$.

Searching the Internet, I have found the definition

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n
=a_0 + 
\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n
+\lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^M a_{-M}.$$

I'm wondering whether this makes sense.

Of course, if both of the limits exist, i.e., $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n=\alpha, \lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^M a_{-M}=\beta$ for some $\alpha, \beta <\infty$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n
=a_0 + \alpha+ \beta,$

and if $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n=\alpha<\infty,\lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^M a_{-M}=-\infty$, then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n=-\infty$.

What about the case of one of the series diverges?

For example, $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n=\infty,\lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{m=1}^M a_{-M}=-\infty$, then the $\infty-\infty$ problem occurs.

In such case, how should I handle $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n$ ?

Comment: Yes "this makes sense".   In your $\infty-\infty$ question, there is no limit overall

Comment: The notations don't have to be strict, you are allowed to write $\sum_{n\in \Bbb{Z}}\frac1{z+n}$, but if you so you need to be perfectly clear that it converges in $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{|n|\le N} \frac1{z+n}$ sense but not in $\lim_{N\to \infty}\lim_{M\to \infty} \sum_{n=-M}^N \frac1{z+n}$ sense.

Comment: It is an analogue of the indeterminate forms we learn in calculus.

Comment: In math, the usual definition of $\sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(\cdots)$ is both limits $\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\lim\limits_{q\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=-p}^q(\cdots)$, $\lim\limits_{q\to\infty}\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=-p}^q(\cdots)$ exists and equal to each other. In other discipline, say in physics,  it may refer to the symmetric limit $\lim\limits_{p\to\infty}\sum\limits_{n=-p}^p (\cdots)$.